# How does "top" calculate CPU usage?

Tags: linux

I'm browsing through the source code of the GNU/Linux program `top`. I am trying to understand how it calculates the CPU usage by each process, but I'm not having much luck.

The source code in question is over at [GitHub](https://github.com/mmalecki/procps/).

Comment: We're not here for "pointers" or "tips". This is a Q&A, not a chat or forum. Ask a concrete, on-topic question please.

Comment: Maybe you should ask in a Forum about the Linux Distro you are interested or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everything else in the *procps* toolkit, the data comes from the `/proc` virtual filesystem, managed by the OS and the Linux kernel. There is no "calculation" involved at all.

Comment: I believe it calculates the percentage of the different CPU usages (by calculating the delta from the previous `/proc` data, and how much of each field is changed) but I agree that all the account of which CPU and what process does what is all handled in the OS.

Comment: @Josten: Then "inform" instead of being rude. In fact, let's settle on not using an arrogant term like "inform", shall we? I disagree that the answer is incorrect. We are simply interpreting the question differently. I believe the OP was referring to a lower level of abstraction that you are, that he wanted to know how `top` obtains the CPU usage data for each process by taking some other data and applying calculations to it. The answer is.... it doesn't. The OS tells it the CPU usage. Yes, `top` runs some post-processing on those values to present them differently, but it's the same data.